# Memory consumption with many goroutines

Tags: memory, go, goroutine

I've put up an http server written in Go and it's getting over a thousands visitors a day. I have an accumulating Goroutine problem(never freed). Over the course of a day I seem to get a little over a thousand of thousand of new Goroutines from the http server.I used `pprof` to check where the problem comes from and I got that:

[Link: memory consumption: SVG pprof](http://creative2.spoti.io/static/pprof.svg)

[image]

Heap:

[image]

Below are tow of my goroutines

```
500 @ 0x410255 0x5a9255 0x5a9e25 0x5aa615 0x5990cf 0x5ada95 0x59d23f 0x4367b1
#   0x5a9255    net._C2func_getaddrinfo+0x55    /usr/local/go/src/net/:26
#   0x5a9e25    net.cgoLookupIPCNAME+0x1c5  /usr/local/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:96
#   0x5aa615    net.cgoLookupIP+0x65        /usr/local/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:148
#   0x5990cf    net.lookupIP+0x5f       /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:64
#   0x5ada95    net.func·026+0x55       /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup.go:79
#   0x59d23f    net.(*singleflight).doCall+0x2f /usr/local/go/src/net/singleflight.go:91

157871 @ 0x423985 0x4239f8 0x411464 0x410c93 0x5a9d68 0x5aa615 0x5990cf 0x5ada95 0x59d23f 0x4367b1
#   0x5a9d68    net.cgoLookupIPCNAME+0x108  /usr/local/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:85
#   0x5aa615    net.cgoLookupIP+0x65        /usr/local/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:148
#   0x5990cf    net.lookupIP+0x5f       /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:64
#   0x5ada95    net.func·026+0x55       /usr/local/go/src/net/lookup.go:79
#   0x59d23f    net.(*singleflight).doCall+0x2f /usr/local/go/src/net/singleflight.go:91
```

Here we can see that **singleflight.go** took the most of goroutints, it's a native library of Go.

my code bolocked in this function

```
func getXmlVast(url string) (string, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.New("request error A(" + err.Error() + ")")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // read xml http response
    xmlData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.New("request error B(" + err.Error() + ")")
    }
    return string(xmlData), nil
}
```

Why Go never freed the goroutines and what **singleflight.go** do.

Comment: most probably - you are not setting timeouts on your http client, so it just hangs there. Why would go "free" a perfectly running goroutine?

Comment: Go routines are like memory in C++ or something. They're not garbage collected or cleaned up automatically or anything. If the method that was invoked by `go SomeMethod()` has not returned by hitting that very explicit `return` keyword then it is going to continue running.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I set a timeout for http.Get() requests and still have the smae problem

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Go version from 1.4 to 1.5 and it soloves the problem.

I did some reserch before to find where the problem comes from I noticed that a lot of peopel have the same problem and no one know why.I think thtat the problem was in the `http/net` library because as I said in my question the function who  took the most of goroutints is **singleflight** and this function is called by `http.Get(url)`